# How do I create a module for a fibonacci sequence in Python on a Mac with TextWrangler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, fibonacci

I've been trying to search up valid sequences online but haven't come across one that works in Python interpreter. Every time I input a sequence, the interpreter always finds some sort of mistake or is not able to formulate a module specific to it that I can import. Along with that, I have not been able to find a downloadable version of the module for Mac.

I've used several sequences. Maybe there are numbers I must input in addition to it? I've been using this sequences in raw form, copying and pasting from a website to TextWrangler:

```
# Fibonacci numbers module

def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print(b, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()

def fib2(n): # return Fibonacci series up to n
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

I am trying to use an importable version in order to solve Project Euler's problem number 2. I'm a beginner and interested in learning more about programming in order to pursue computational sciences.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a file named `fibonacci.py`:

```
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print(b, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()

def fib2(n): # return Fibonacci series up to n
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

Then open an other file `__main__.py` in the same folder as `fibonacci.py`.
The content of `__main__.py` should be:

```
import fibonacci
print(fibonacci.fib(3))
```

Then you can execute the `__main__.py` file and it should work.

Comment: I cannot run the fibonacci.py file through terminal because it has an invalid syntax in the 4th line at the equal sign. When you say execute, do you mean running the file through terminal? I don't understand how you open files in the same folder. On Textwrangler, whenever I try to open another file, it just looks at another document.

Is the file __main__.py a file that I create?

Comment: `__main__.py` and `fibonacci.py` are two files in the same directory. When you execute `__main__.py` then it imports fibonacci.